# How to update activity when dialog is closed

Tags: android

I am creating a custom dialog class in which I extend the default Dialog. I am doing some work there. Once the user closes the dialog, how can my activity know that the dialog is closed and time to update the screen views with results?

Do I pass an instance from my activity to the Dialog class so I can call a public method on it? Or is there a better design?

Thank you

Comment: You should be able to utilize the `onActivityResult` http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: OnActivityResult is used to start activity. I am starting a dialog

Comment: Is your Activity the one that launches your dialog?  What's wrong with just having the Activity call setOnDismissListener(DialogInterface.OnDismissListener listener) on the dialog and then implementing void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what I'll do is this:

1. Create an Interface, for example: OnDialogCloseListener, with a method called onDialogClose()
2. The activity have to implement that interface and override the onDialogClose() method
3. Create an attribute in yout Dialog class of OnDialogCloseListener type and a  constructor method and when you create the Dialog pass the activity as a parameter.

   ```
   OnDialogCloseListener listener;
   public MyDialog(OnDialogCloseListener listener) { 
       this.listener = listener;
   }
   ```
4. Now in your onClick method of the close button of your Dialog call the method of the interface. Ex.:

   ```
    listener.onDialogClose();
   ```
5. And finally in your activity class in the method that you override from OnDialogCloseListener do whatever you want when the Dialog is close.

Note: You can create all the methods that you want in the interface a call each one whatever you want, not only when the dialog is close, you may have other events that you want check when raised.

Hope that can help you

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

create an interface in your dialog class:

```
public interface NoticeDialogListener {
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
}
```

Register a listener in onAttach() :

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
    try {
        // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the host
        mListener = (NoticeDialogListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement NoticeDialogListener");
    }
}
```

And implement that interface in your calling activity.

Comment: I am using activity and Dialog with no fragments. So no onAttach(Activity method)

Answer (score 0):

A dialog overrides several methods that sense when the dialog is closing. The include

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}

 @Override
public void setOnCancelListener(@Nullable OnCancelListener listener) {
    super.setOnCancelListener(listener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}
```

These methods all detect that action of closing a dialog. However, the most efficient one that I suggest you use is

```
@Override
public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(), "Dialog had disappeared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
}
```